# Microsoft read aloud not working on slow connection

Tags: microsoft-edge

I use Microsoft read aloud built-in ms edge, but it doesn't work properly when my download speed is slower than a point.
Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because, since, Microsoft Edge runs off of your internet, so does most of it's built in tools. The tools need to get a connection between your computer and Microsoft's servers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).